# Is it ok to override completionBlock property of NSOperation with different parameter types?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-blocks, nsoperation

[Marcus Zarra's "Core Data" (2nd edition)](https://pragprog.com/book/mzcd2/core-data) book lists an example where in an `NSOperation` subclass he overrides the `completionBlock` property:

```
@property (copy) void (^completionBlock)(void) NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0);
```

with

```
typedef void (^ExportCompletionBlock)(NSData *jsonData, NSError *error);
@property (nonatomic, copy) ExportCompletionBlock completionBlock;
```

which in Xcode 6 under 10.10 results in the following warnings:

```
‘atomic’ attribute on property ‘completionBlock’ does not match the property inherited from ‘NSOperation’
```

and

```
Property type ‘ExportCompletionBlock’ (aka ‘void(^)(NSData *_strong, NSError *_strong)’) is incompatible with type ‘void(^)(void)’ inherited from ‘NSOperation’
```

Now I wonder what I should make of these warnings.
What about the atomicity attribute?
Is it ok to change the parameters despite the warning?
Is there another, better solution that does not involve changing the block parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What about the atomicity attribute?

Going from `atomic` to `nonatomic` is really confusing. NSOperation is one place where atomic properties are needed. Unless you have a very good reason, I would stick with `atomic`.

> Is it ok to change the parameters despite the warning?

The warning is there for a reason. The `completionBlock` property is expected to work a certain way, if it somehow gets called with its original signature (`self.completionBlock()`) instead of the redefined signature (`self.completionBlock(jsonData, error)`), then your app will crash.

> Is there another, better solution that does not involve changing the block parameters?

Don't redefine `completionBlock`. You are not forced to use `completionBlock`, create a new property with a different name. For example, In your subclass, you could use `exportCompletionBlock`:

```
@property (atomic, copy) ExportCompletionBlock exportCompletionBlock;
```

Then, in `-main`, call `self.exportCompletionBlock(jsonData, error)` when the operation has finished instead of `self.completionBlock(jsonData, error)`.

Comment: "You are not forced to use completionBlock, create a new property with a different name." This seems to work. But how would I have learned about it? Also the documentation on `completionBlock` says: "In iOS 8 and later and OS X v10.10 and later, this property is set to nil after the completion block begins executing." Will this also happen with my own block property with a different name?

Comment: @MartinW I don't know how to answer your first question. You control everything inside of `-main` in your subclass, so you can do whatever you wish. If you don't call `-completionBlock`, then it's a unused property.

Comment: @MartinW As for your second question, `NSOperation` doesn't know about your subclass's properties. I would be very surprised if the value was changed.

Comment: The concern of my second question was more: do I have to do something else to my custom `exportCompletionBlock` property, something that NSOperation does with the `completionBlock` property and I don't know about. At the moment, all I do is setting `exportCompletionBlock` and then calling it at the end of my `main` method.

Comment: Jeffery Thomas wrote: "You control everything inside of -main in your subclass ... If you don't call -completionBlock, then it's a unused property." This is not quite correct: if implemented completionBlock is automatically called as soon NSOperations' isFinished property is set to true. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperation/1408085-completionblock

Comment: @ElisevanLooij Yes, the doc is clear:  `completionBlock` is called when `finished` is set to `true`. I don't know what I was thinking in 2015, maybe a think-o on my part or something in `NSOperation` changed.